# TypeError: metaclass "takes no arguments"

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Why do we get an error for the following code:

```
class StateMeta:
    def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
    # end __call__
# end StateMeta

class State(metaclass=StateMeta):
    pass
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/tempHSHDFHS).py", line 7, in <module>
    class State(metaclass=StateMeta):
TypeError: StateMeta() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to have your meta class inherit from `type`, write `StateMeta(type)` instead of `StateMeta`.

Comment: Why do you have to inherit from type?

Answer (score 0):

The emulation of callable objects via `__call__` is meant to work on **instances** of the defining class, not on the defining class itself. So, you have to use an instance of your class `StateMeta`:

```
class StateMeta:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Called StateMeta")
        pass
    
state_meta = StateMeta()
class State(metaclass=state_meta):
    pass
```

Besides of that and somewhat surprisingly, you can use a **function** as a metaclass:

```
def meta(*args, **kwargs):
    print("meta()", args, kwargs)
    return object

class A(metaclass=meta):
    pass
```